# Logitech mouse and keyboard on same receiver sometimes not recognized - hard restart necessary

Tags: 12.10, logitech, wireless-keyboards, logitech-unifying

I have mouse **Logitech M505** and keyboard **Logitech K340** on same usb wireless receiver. My Ubuntu is up to date.

Problem is that sometimes **ubuntu doesn't recognize devices** - Lately very often.
I seat in front of my login screen and I can't do anything. Even blinking cursor stops in welcome password field. Mostly hard reset is a rescue.

Sometimes helps when I unplug Logitech usb reciver and plug it again, wait about 2 minutes and try to hit some buttons on my keyboard. Then there is a chance to back to live those two devices.

In my Windows 7 everything is all right.

System Details are:

```
Linux version 3.5.0-22-generic (buildd@komainu) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) ) #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 8 21:47:00 UTC 2013
CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T
```

`syslog` when I plug receiver again:

```
Jan 29 10:55:41 maraspc kernel: [   47.957167] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan 29 10:55:56 maraspc kernel: [   63.129217] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan 29 10:55:56 maraspc kernel: [   63.344590] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Jan 29 10:56:01 maraspc kernel: [   68.350208] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:56:07 maraspc kernel: [   73.455350] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:56:07 maraspc kernel: [   73.670676] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
Jan 29 10:56:12 maraspc kernel: [   78.676325] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:56:17 maraspc kernel: [   83.781466] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:56:17 maraspc kernel: [   83.885163] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.399657] usb 4-4: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.572237] usb 4-4: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.572248] usb 4-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.572255] usb 4-4: Product: USB Receiver
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.572261] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Logitech
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-4"
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.641141] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.641148] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.654283] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:12.0-4/input2
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.660522] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2007 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-4/4-4:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input11
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.660761] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2007] on usb-0000:00:12.0-4:1
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.661595] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101d as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-4/4-4:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input12
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.662046] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101d] on usb-0000:00:12.0-4:2
Jan 29 10:56:18 maraspc kernel: [   84.838379] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Successfully made thread 2228 of process 2228 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc dbus[848]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' (using servicehelper)
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc udisksd[2236]: udisks daemon version 2.0.0 starting
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Successfully made thread 2241 of process 2228 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc dbus[848]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc udisksd[2236]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Successfully made thread 2262 of process 2228 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Successfully made thread 2263 of process 2228 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jan 29 10:56:29 maraspc rtkit-daemon[1745]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jan 29 10:56:31 maraspc goa[2385]: goa-daemon version 3.6.0 starting [main.c:112, main()]
Jan 29 10:56:33 maraspc kernel: [   99.930587] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan 29 10:56:48 maraspc kernel: [  115.126635] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan 29 10:56:49 maraspc kernel: [  115.365908] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
Jan 29 10:57:04 maraspc kernel: [  130.458223] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan 29 10:57:19 maraspc kernel: [  145.654204] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan 29 10:57:19 maraspc kernel: [  145.893523] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci_hcd
Jan 29 10:57:24 maraspc kernel: [  150.899131] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:57:29 maraspc kernel: [  156.004348] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:57:30 maraspc kernel: [  156.243534] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci_hcd
Jan 29 10:57:32 maraspc dbus[848]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.SystemService' (using servicehelper)
Jan 29 10:57:32 maraspc dbus[848]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.SystemService'
Jan 29 10:57:35 maraspc kernel: [  161.249161] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:57:40 maraspc kernel: [  166.354371] usb 7-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 29 10:57:40 maraspc kernel: [  166.457958] hub 7-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

Answer (score 0):

ok , so i got logitech m525 wireless mouse with unifying receiver, just happen for a second time that it out of nowhere stopped working.

I would like to note that it's second time that's happening, for a first time i got my mouse replaced by warranty.

So the thing is that i use this mouse with my laptop which i carry to work for and use it a home more or less daily, so it's approximately(at least) 2 cycles of in/out daily.

And even nicer thing is that why i decided to write here is: if you put the unifying receiver only half way inside usb socket it start to work, so the thing is that unifying receiver wears out due to sadly not that intensive use.. maybe it's not the windows thing?

(if you thing that it's single usb socket's issue, no it's not, it's the same with all 4 i got on my laptop)